# Android if-else code not working properly

Tags: android, if-statement

The problem i am facing is that i have my code is executing "else" block even when the "if " condition is true.

```
public class MsgNewPackage extends Activity {


    private DatabaseHandler dbhandler;
     private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
     private  ListView listView;

     String PKG_NAME,PKG_DUR,PKG_PRICE,PKG_ITEMS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_msg_new_package);





         dbhandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);


          displayListView();
    }




private void displayListView() 


    {

    String check= "Mobilink";

     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String conn = intent.getStringExtra("NET_CONN");
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), conn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

     if(conn == check)
     {


        Cursor cursor = dbhandler.fetchAllMOBSMSPackages();

         String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_PKG_NAME,DatabaseHandler.KEY_NO_OF_FREE_ITEMS,DatabaseHandler.KEY_DURATION,DatabaseHandler.KEY_CHARGES};

         // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
          int[] to = new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.no_of_item,R.id.duration,R.id.pkgcharges};

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
          //as well as the layout information
          dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row2, cursor,columns,to);

           listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          // Assign adapter to ListView
          listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

     } 


     else


     {  

            Cursor cursor = dbhandler.fetchAllSMSPackages();


             String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_PKG_NAME,DatabaseHandler.KEY_NO_OF_FREE_ITEMS,DatabaseHandler.KEY_DURATION,DatabaseHandler.KEY_CHARGES};

             // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
              int[] to = new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.no_of_item,R.id.duration,R.id.pkgcharges};

            // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
              //as well as the layout information
              dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row2, cursor,columns,to);

               listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
              // Assign adapter to ListView
              listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
     }
```

The toast displays that conn has "Mobilink" but the listview gets populated with results of fetchAllSMSPackages() (i.e function called in else block ) which should not be the case. Pleas help.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `conn.equals(check)` instead of `conn == check`.

Strings in Java are objects, and not primitives, so you cannot compare their value using `==`. This will compare the object as a whole, and not the text.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.equals()` when comparing String values. Not ==.

Try using:

```
conn.equals(check);
```